# How (is it possible) to access class members using iterators in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Before, when using normal for-loop I would access it like this:

```
this->customClassCustomVectorArray[i]->getCustomMember();
```

But now I dont know how to access it because when I type "->" VS2010 doesnt offer any members or methods.

```
for(vector<CustomClass*>::iterator it = this->customClassCustomVectorArray.begin(); it != this->customClassCustomVectorArray.end(); ++it){
    cout << this->customClassCustomVectorArray[*it]->getCustomMember() << endl;
}
```

Ive tried "*it" and "it" but nothing happens. Is this even possible? I suppose it should be.

Comment: `*it` gets to the actual object so just do `*it->getCustomMember()`

Comment: You mean when you type `->` MSVC++2010 doesn't list any method? If yes, you should include `MSVC++2010` in tags.

Comment: also `for(CustomClass* ptr : customClassCustomVectorArray) ptr->getCustomMember();`

Comment: _"I dont know how to access it because when I type '->' VS2010 doesnt offer any members or methods."_ Sigh. IDEs. They encourage you to rely on "intellisense" instead of developing some sense of your own. :(

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: What? The two questions bear _no_ resemblance to each other beyond being about "iteration", vaguely, and being questions on SO.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Sorry, I went by accessing class members by iteration, from the title.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Traditionally we _read_ questions before making judgements about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cout << this->customClassCustomVectorArray[*it]->getCustomMember() << endl;
```

That is not right. `[]` expects a numeric index into the vector, but `*it` is not a numeric index. It is an iterator. It already points to the correct position in the vector.

```
cout << (*it)->getCustomMember() << endl;
```

`[]` is only for when you are iterating using numeric indices, not iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong:

```
this->customClassCustomVectorArray[*it]->getCustomMember()
```

Right:

```
(*it)->getCustomMember()
```

Why? Because `it` is very much like

```
this->customClassCustomVectorArray + i
```

In fact, it's exactly the same as

```
this->customClassCustomVectorArray.begin() + i
```

so you don't need to say

```
this->customClassCustomVectorArray
```

twice.

Answer (score 0):

While @Lightness's answer is correct as far as it goes, it still doesn't point toward how you should be doing this. Most times that you write an explicit loop using iterators, it's a mistake (and this is no exception). Most uses of `std::endl` are also mistakes (and this doesn't look like an exception in that respect either).

So, instead of writing an explicit loop, then explicitly dereferencing the iterator, etc., and finally taking his advice (correct though it is) to get the syntax correct, you should be thinking in terms of getting rid of essentially all of that, and using generic algorithms to do the job instead.

In this case, you have an input collection. For each item in that input collection, you're invoking a function, then writing the result to some output collection. That pretty much describes `std::transform`, so it's probably a decent fit for the job at hand.

```
std::transform(customClassCustomVectorArray.begin(),
               customClassCustomVectorArray.end(),
               mem_fun(&customClass::customMember),
               std::ostream_iterator<result_type>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

This uses `result_type` to represent the type of the result from invoking your member function. Having to explicitly specify that result type is something of a liability of this technique, but at least IMO, its strengths substantially outweigh that minor liability.

Probably the most obvious strength is that the definition of `std::transform` is (reasonably) well known and standardized, so anybody who knows C++ (at all well) immediately has a pretty fair idea of what this is supposed to do as a whole--invoke some function on every item in a range, and write the returned value to some destination.